# How can I call a directive function from outside?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that generates a list for me. This directive has methods for pagination. I would like to control this list using keyboard so that when I press left or right the list pages next or previous.

Is there anyway I could do that?

bellow there is my directive code:

```
app.directive("gridview", function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',  
        transclude: true,           
        template:'<div><button ng-disabled="!hasPrevious()" ng-click="onPrev()"> Previous </button><button ng-disabled="!hasNext()" ng-click="onNext()"> Next </button></div><div ng-transclude></div>',
        scope:{ 
            'currentItem':'=',
            'currentPage':'=',
            'pageLimit':'=',
            'data':'=',
            'totalPages' :'&'
        },
        link:function($scope, element, attrs){

            $scope.size = function(){
                return angular.isDefined($scope.data) ? $scope.data.length : 0;
            };

            $scope.end = function(){
                return $scope.start() + $scope.pageLimit;
            };

            $scope.start = function(){
                return $scope.currentPage * $scope.pageLimit;
            };

            $scope.totalPages = function(){
                $scope.totalPages({theTotal : $scope.size});
            };

            $scope.page = function(){
                return !!$scope.size() ? ( $scope.currentPage + 1 ) : 0;
            };

            $scope.hasNext = function(){
                return $scope.page() < ( $scope.size() /  $scope.pageLimit )  ;
            };

            $scope.onNext = function(){
                $scope.currentPage = parseInt($scope.currentPage) + 1;
                $scope.currentItem = parseInt($scope.currentPage) + 1; 
            };

            $scope.hasPrevious = function(){
                return !!$scope.currentPage;
            } ;

            $scope.onPrev = function(){
                $scope.currentPage=$scope.currentPage-1;
            };                
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Add listener inside the directive for keypress events - just remember to destroy them, using `$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){ //kill event here})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always use the Angular event system, which will allow you to interact between your controller and directive.

Simply broadcast an event in your controller and listen to it in your directive to call the function you want.

**Controller**

```
$scope.$broadcast('onPrev')
```

**Directive**

```
$scope.$on('onPrev', function () {
  $scope.onPrev()
})
```

that's for the main question, but your more specific problem, you should have a look to [ngKeypress](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)

Comment: Is there anyway to access the scope methods using angular.element(###).scope().onNext() ?

Comment: The `angular.element` refer to the **jQLite** object of your directive, you can't access to your scope using that

Comment: Hi, Sorry to bother u, wouldn't that work?

http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/nukRe/light/

Comment: I really don't understand why you use this extra `ajaxResultPost` function. Also you have angular, so stop using `onClick` from vanilla and switch to `ng-click`. If you really want to do an ajax call no problem I've updated your [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xb0otate/) a bit to show that.

Comment: I am trying to do an app for smartTVs using angular. On these devices the main input is using a remote control. The remote control keys are understood as keyboard events. So that when I press on the control Up, Down, etc. I can catch the respective keypress event. 
What I would like to do is when I press any key I would call a method of my directive. But I can't manage to achieve that.