# Center a Google Maps (defined in a directive) with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I decided to created a custom map with my markers (that I defined) with a search function among my markers.
I have a mymarkers.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.constant("myMarkers", [{
   lat='..',
   lng='..'
 },{
   lat='..',
   lng='..'
}]);
```

An app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller("myController", ["$scope", "myMarkers",    function($scope, myMarkers){
    $scope.markers= myMarkers; 
    $scope.searchMarkers = function(arr,obj){..};
    $scope.centerMapOnMarker = function (marker){..} <--
    }]);    
app.directive('myMap', ["myMarkers", function(myMarkers) {
        // directive link function
        var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var map, infoWindow;
            var markers = [];
            // map config
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.849005, 2.337674),
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scrollwheel: true
            };

        // init the map
        function initMap() {..}    

        // place a marker
        function setMarker(map, position, title, content,link) {..}

        function returnMarker(){..}
        // show the map and place some markers
        initMap();

        for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(myMarkers[i].lat, myMarkers[i].lng), myMarkers[i].title, myMarkers[i].content, myMarkers[i].icon);
        }

    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

and an index.html

```
<div my-map=""></div>

<div class="myresearch">
            <input placeholder="Search a place" ng-model="search">
                <div ng-show="search.length">
                <p ng-repeat="marker in markers | filter: search"> 
                    <span ng-click="centerMapOnMarker(marker)"> <--
                    <img class="icon-search" ng-src="{{marker.icon}}" /> 
                    <label class="textr"> {{marker.title}} </label> </p>
                    </span>
                </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to center the map on my marker when I click on it. But I have a problem because the map is defined in the directive and I cannot access to it.
When I try to re-use it, in my controller and my html (with the <-- arrow), I have the obvious bug : `map isn't defined` so I don't know how to do it and how to re-use the `var map` defined in my directive, in my controller.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the angular event system.

See the accepted answer here - [How can I call a directive function from outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855811/how-can-i-call-a-directive-function-from-outside)

So in your controller you could do

```
$scope.centerMapOnMarker = function (marker){
        $scope.$broadcast('center-on-marker', marker);
    }
```

And in your directive:

```
scope.$on('center-on-marker', function (event, args) {
  //do you centering logic here by accessing marker from args param
});
```

Comment: I notice that I have a problem with the `var center = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng);`I don't know why it doesn't succed to understand my latitude and my longitude altough my marker.js has this type `{
                lat: 48.850292, 
                lng: 2.330776}`

Comment: If it can help : 
When I use `console.log(marker)`in the `scope.$on('center-on-marker', function (marker) {
  //do you centering logic here..
});` in the directive. I have this answer in my console : `Object {name: "center-on-marker", targetScope: Scope, defaultPrevented: false, currentScope: Scope}` and not the marker

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer, the first param to the listener is actually the event itself, just need a second args param to access the marker

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you. The event is always the first param of a listener ?

Comment: Yes i forgot that in my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your directive -> `setMarker` method

```
marker.addListener("click", function() {
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
});
```

If you want your controller to know about the click you can emit an event:

```
// Code for your directive -> setMarker method
marker.addListener("click", function() {
    scope.$emit("gmaps.marker.click", map, marker);
});

// Add this to your controller
this.$scope.$on("gmaps.marker.click", function(event, map, marker) {
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    // Do other stuff...
});
```

Comment: Thank it works in order to center the map when I click on a marker of the map. But I would like to have a search menu, click on the search results and then have the map moved (with the `ng-click`)